# How to subset a dataframe based on columns from another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two data frames (`df1` and `df2`) and I want to subset df2 based on the first two columns contained in df1. For example,

```
df1 = data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,1,1),y=c(1,2,3,4,5),value=c(3,4,5,6,7))
df2 = data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,1,1,2), y=c(5,3,4,2,1,6), value=c(8,9,10,11,12,13))
```

[image]

As we can see, row 6 `(2,6)` in `df2`  is not included in `df1`, so I will just select row 1 to row 5 in df2.

Also, I want to rearrange `df2` based on `df1`. The final result should be like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: One possible solution is `df1 %>% select(x,y) %>% inner_join(df2, by=c("x","y"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using merge, by default the data frames are joined by the variables they have in common, and the results are sorted. So you can do:

```
merge(df2, df1[c('x', 'y')])

#   x y value
# 1 1 1    12
# 2 1 2    11
# 3 1 3     9
# 4 1 4    10
# 5 1 5     8
```

To sort by the order of `df1`, use @Mankind_008's method

```
merge(df1[c('x','y')], df2 , sort = F)
```

Example:

```
set.seed(0)
df1 <- df1[sample(seq_len(nrow(df1))),]
df2 <- df2[sample(seq_len(nrow(df2))),]
df1
#   x y value
# 5 1 5     7
# 2 1 2     4
# 4 1 4     6
# 3 1 3     5
# 1 1 1     3    
merge(df1[c('x','y')], df2 , sort = F)
#   x y value
# 1 1 5     8
# 2 1 2    11
# 3 1 4    10
# 4 1 3     9
# 5 1 1    12
```

Comment: To keep the order of df1, should be: `merge(df1[c('x','y')], df2 , sort = False)`

Comment: yup values will be the same only but order will not be. That is because df1 is already sorted in the given dummy case, in general case i.e. df1 is original scrambled, it will not retain the structure if sort = True

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just one thing to mention that `sort=FALSE` should be the right format (not `False`).

Comment: @Yang Yang You are welcome. you are right. Ryan added with a synonym 'F' in answer. so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Use data tables:

```
library(data.table)
```

Create your data as data.table:

```
df1 <- data.table( x = c(1,1,1,1,1), y = c(1,2,3,4,5), value = c(3,4,5,6,7) )
df2 <- data.table( x = c(1,1,1,1,1,2), y = c(5,3,4,2,1,6), value = c(8,9,10,11,12,13) )
```

Or convert your existing data.frames:

```
df1 <- as.data.table( df1 )
df2 <- as.data.table( df2 )
```

Then:

```
df2[ df1, on = .(x,y) ]
```

Any column in df1 that have the same name in df2 will be renamed as i.columnname:

```
   x y value i.value
1: 1 1    12       3
2: 1 2    11       4
3: 1 3     9       5
4: 1 4    10       6
5: 1 5     8       7
```

Note that it already order by x and y. If you want to order by the column 'value' (or any other):

```
df2[ df1, on = .(x,y) ][ order(value) ]
```

The advantage of using data.table (or dplyr, as the solution proposed by AntoniosK) is that you can keep the two data sets separated.